# How can I use Animation on Image View on View controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, animation, ios8

I want to use below code on image view,

```
NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-0"],

                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-1"],

                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-2"],

                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-3"],

                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-4"],

                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-5"],

                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-6"],

                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-7"],nil];

UIButton *barButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[barButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-0"] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // mine trick

[barButton.imageView setAnimationImages:imageArray];

[barButton.imageView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];


[barButton.imageView startAnimating];

[barButton sizeToFit];


self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:barButton];


Now I want to use this code on Image view, Please check

.m file

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageContactList;

@synthesize imageContactList;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

 [super viewDidLoad];

 [self ContactListAnimated];

}

 UIImageView*animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    animationView.animationImages = 
                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"],

                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"],

                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"],

                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.gif"],

                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.gif"],

                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.gif"],nil];

    animationView.animationDuration = 1.25;

    animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

    [animationView startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:animationView];
```

Please tell me where I am wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: what is the issue? and I see your code is not in a method.

Comment: if you have an imageview outlet, why are you creating it again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code you used should work. As I see, you are creating an imageView where you already have one. Use the outlet you have in your .m file

```
NSArray *animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.gif"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"images1.jpg"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"images2.jpg"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"images3.jpg"],
                    nil];

    //imageContactList is the UIImageView
    imageContactList.animationImages=animationArray;
    imageContactList.animationDuration=1.5;
imageContactList.animationRepeatCount=0;
    [imageContactList startAnimating];
```